# Create a COLOR image in Python from Matlab data

Tags: python, image, matlab, png, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create COLOR images in Python. The data is get from a Matlab file. 
Here my code. Actually i can create only gray scale images but i need color images.
Could you help me ?

The data of the Matlab file is 512x512x200 Double array.

```
> {'__version__': '1.0', 'St3D': array([[[ -4.98510788e-02, 
> -4.98139346e-02,  -4.97636073e-02, ...,
>           -5.19862428e-02,  -5.20095813e-02,  -5.20122990e-02],
>         [ -4.98249255e-02,  -4.97792210e-02,  -4.97507640e-02, ...,
>           -5.19832396e-02,  -5.19884452e-02,  -5.20089354e-02],
>         [ -4.98121755e-02,  -4.97751679e-02,  -4.97488529e-02, ...,
>           -5.19605824e-02,  -5.19734534e-02,  -5.20023879e-02],
>         ...,
>        [[  9.10799464e-05,   1.75287655e-04,   2.26928715e-04, ...,
>            1.10619951e-04,   1.04038395e-04,   7.44506576e-05],
>         [  6.29097917e-05,   1.20765020e-04,   1.91577341e-04, ...,
>            8.24078623e-05,   8.96774520e-05,   7.44268856e-05],
>         [  4.14273859e-05,   7.96562916e-05,   1.20801256e-04, ...,
>            9.05750282e-05,   8.13201896e-05,   6.77554603e-05],
>         ..., 
>         [  1.72297366e-04,   1.68849830e-04,   2.21771692e-04, ...,
>            2.30046391e-04,   2.51247428e-04,   2.58021432e-04],
>         [  2.06350049e-04,   1.92126121e-04,   2.58923928e-04, ...,
>            2.48977658e-04,   2.78131275e-04,   2.76242136e-04],
>         [  2.42915268e-04,   2.47607632e-04,   2.89283796e-04, ...,
>            2.58819021e-04,   2.76203977e-04,   2.82977241e-04]]]), '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri
> Sep 19 17:03:17 2014', '__globals__': []}


#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scipy.io
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image
##import Image 
import numpy as np

import timeit
fDataName = 'MatLab_File'

start_time = timeit.default_timer()

# import file into a dictionary
fMatLab = scipy.io.loadmat(fDataName, mat_dtype = True, squeeze_me = True, struct_as_record=False)
# read in the structure
data = fMatLab[fDataName]

sizeZ = data.shape[2]

for i in range(sizeZ):    
   img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], low=-0, high=255, mode='L')
   img.save('imageFinal_%s.png' % i)

stop_time = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print("--- %s seconds ---" % stop_time)
```

An example of the create image with the code is : 
[image]

The color image needed is like : 
[image]

The color image was create with this code :

```
pyA = data[:,:,1] 
from pylab import * 
from matplotlib import *
matshow(pyA,1) 
show()
```

I also used this fragment of code:

```
for i in range(sizeZ):    
    img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], low=0, high=255, mode='L')
    img.save('transectxyi_%s.png' % i)
    im = Image.fromarray(data[:,:,i]).convert('RGBA')
    im.save("a.png")
```

but i get black images. The black image is like :
[image]

**EDIT**: I solved my problem with the code:

```
def saveImages(data, fileName): 
    img = scipy.misc.toimage(data, low=0, high=255, mode='P')    
    imP = img.convert('RGBA')    
    img = mpimg.pil_to_array(imP)
    imgP = img[:,:,0]    
    plt.imsave(fileName, imgP, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None, format=None, origin=None, dpi=100)
    return imP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `img` you have has only one channel (grayscale), so what you need is pseudo color visualization.

see http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

so the code in your for-loop might look like:

```
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
imgplot.set_cmap('spectral')
#save the plot with savefig() http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html
```

Comment: Hi, in my case i don't plot the image only take the information from matlab and save severals images with color

Comment: Finally i solve the problem, you can see my EDIT. Thanks its works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIL` for this like so:

```
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
```

or you can use:

```
img = Image.fromarray(data).convert('RGB')
```

Also, in the line, `img = scipy.misc.toimage(data[:,:,i], low=-0, high=255, mode='L')`, you have `low=-0` which I'm guessing you want to be `low=0` without the `-`.

Comment: Non. I actualize the questions because with your comment i get black images without COLOR.

Comment: @user3410517 are you defining `dtype=float32` or `dytpe=uint8` in your array? Also, try my code outside of the loop rather than calling it on every iteration.

Comment: I changed the code but the image is already black data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float32) and i can't move your code outside the loop because i need generate several images